# IDE to develop rqt projects

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have worked with ROS packages earlier which uses catkin environment. I have also worked on Qt projects developed in Qt Creator which does not use catkin environment.
I have also seen Qt projects in ROS like [Image Viewer](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_image_view).
Qt has different build folder and the items inside it whereas catkin has different directory structure. My query is how to use Qt in ROS environment?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385927/ide-to-develop-rqt-projects/) by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2021-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-07**:
You are using QT 4 or QT5?

**Comment by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on 2021-09-07**:
Using Qt5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some more survey I found that ROS uses a different Qt Creator Plug-in. The installer can be found [here](https://ros-qtc-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I m using Ubuntu 20.04 and as per the reference page the installer is provided till 18.04 and fortunately it works for 20.04 as well.
Complete process, from installation to project execution is nicely compiled in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7_M1i7T-go).

---

Originally posted by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) with karma: 47 on 2021-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-11**:
Thank you for sharing. Great video